# Angular 13 inherited class cannot access ViewChild

Tags: angular

I am unable to use `ViewChild` with a string reference due to Angular sanitizing the `#id` tag from my HTML template.

`template.html`

```
        
    <div [ngClass]="htmlClass">
        <a #inset name="inset" class="anchor" [ngClass]="htmlClass"></a>
    </div>
```

`my-component.ts`

```
    export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {       

        public htmlClass = "dashboard-widget DASHBOARD";
        constructor() {
          super();
        }
```

`base-component.ts`

```
    @Injectable()
    export abstract class BaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {       
        @ViewChild('inset') contentInsetView: any;
    }
```

This results in the following rendered HTML:

```
        
    <div _ngcontent-dkm-c114="" class="dashboard-widget DASHBOARD" ng-reflect-ng-class="dashboard-widget DASHBOARD ">
        <a _ngcontent-dkm-c114="" name="inset" class="anchor dashboard-widget DASHBOARD" ng-reflect-ng-class="dashboard-widget DASHBOARD "></a>
    </div>
```

This results in the view child never being set:

```
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.warn("AfterInit: ", this.contentInsetView);
      }
```

```
    AfterInit:  undefined
```

This code was working in prior Angular versions (version 9), any ideas?

**UPDATED:**
Added inherited class which seems to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell angular what it should read from `inset`.

The correct way to use `@ViewChild` is:

```
@ViewChild('selector', { read: ElementRef }) element?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
```

---

If I know, that the selector will never disappear (is not inside a `*ngIf`), I give ViewChild decorator `static: true` and `element!: ElementRef<...>`.

```
@ViewChild('selector', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) element!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
```

I do this because the `static` means, that when `ngOnInit` hook is fired, the element will be defined, and it is *mostly* safe to use it everywhere.

Comment: by default it should take ElementRef.  

In my actual code I have  @ViewChild('inset', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }).   

placing the code onto stackblitz and I have traced the issue further to be related to  component inheritance.  I will update the question further.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue.

In order to inherit a Component in angular you must create another component complete with @Component decorator.

Answer (score -1):

You have to decorate BaseComponent with @Directive()

```
@Directive()
export abstract class BaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {       
    @ViewChild('inset') contentInsetView: any;
}
```